# Counting integers in array from 1 to 100 in increments of 10

Tags: ruby

```
a = Array.new(200) { rand(1..100) }.sort!

puts a.count{ |a| (a >  0 && a < 11) }
puts a.count{ |b| (b > 10 && b < 21) }
puts a.count{ |c| (c > 20 && c < 31) }

puts a.inspect
```

So I can just repeat this all the way to 100 which works but I'm looking for a short cut to hopefully count all the digits pairs with the single line at the top(Add onto the single line). Hopefully each 10 (1-10, 11-20, etc) has a different variable that I can call later on. Or at-least be able to convert it.

make variables like

```
b = a.count{ |c| (c > 20 && c < 31) }
```

so later i could use it to make a string like

```
puts "#" * b
```

so the end result of it all will look like below

```
1-10 #########################
11-20 ##############################
21-30 ######################
```

each # representing how much 1-10 there were.

Comment: This is plain Ruby, and Ruby on Rails tags are absolutely not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
counts = 10.times.map { |i| (i + 1)...(i + 11) }.map { |range|
  a.count { |x| range.include? x }
}

counts[0]
# => 17   (number of numbers in 1...11)
counts[1]
# => 20   (number of numbers in 11...21)
counts[2]
# => 22   (number of numbers in 21...31)
# ...
```

EDIT: Or even easier, by exploiting a simple mathematical property:

```
counts = a.group_by { |x| (x - 1) / 10 }.map { |k, v| v.count }
```

> Hopefully each 10 (1-10, 11-20, etc) has a different variable that I can call later on.

Why would you want different variables when you can have an array?

EDIT2: Whole program, in 1-4 lines:

```
array = 200.times.map { rand(1..100) }.sort
array.group_by { |x| (x - 1) / 10 }.each do |k, v|
  puts "%2d-%2d %s" % [k * 10 + 1, k * 10 + 10, "#" * v.count]
end
```

Translation: Do two hundred iterations, and construct an array, such that each element is a random number between 1 and 100. Then group the array by the result of division by 10 (adjusting by 1 so we don't get ranges of 0-9, 10-19...); iterating on the hash containing the division result and items, print the bounds (reconstructing the start and the end from the division result) and also a number of hashes corresponding to the number of items in each group.

EDIT3: As Stefan notes, we can use `chunk` because the array is sorted, for a bit of a speedup. `group_by` above doesn't care about the array being sorted. You can simply replace `group_by` with `chunk` even though they return different types, simply because iterating on hashes works the same way as iterating on array of two-element arrays.

```
array = 200.times.map { rand(1..100) }.sort
array.chunk { |x| (x - 1) / 10 }.each do |k, v|
  puts "%2d-%2d %s" % [k * 10 + 1, k * 10 + 10, "#" * v.count]
end
```

Comment: b= a.count{|c| (c > 20 && c < 31)}

Comment: b= a.count{|c| (c > 20 && c < 31)}

Comment: crap, I can't type a space.. anyways. I want to make variable so I can do a simple function with a variable of how much 1-10 there were like puts "#" * b

Comment: And why would you want to do that? In my variant you could just do `puts "#" * counts[1]`, and get the equivalent result without the repetition. Finally, it allows me to do `counts.each { |c| puts "#" * c }`. Whenever you have a number of things that all behave the same, arrays are always, *always* better than individual variables.

Comment: Well, I'm not very good at ruby so I'm still trying to figure out exactly what your code just said. Also like I said I want to be about to finish this whole program with 1-4 lines. I'm trying to overachieve :l

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks but I'm going to have to learn this not copy. I'm a student so ya. It seems correct but I added an     puts array.inspect     it didn't quite match the results. The method is definitely on point though.

Comment: If you don't use the tricks I did, you can't write this in 4 lines. But yeah, definitely try to learn; the most important lesson from today is - arrays are your friend, using individual variables is Bad (tm).

Comment: nvm, might of miss counted. hmm seems good. I'll probably try to digest this and hopefully create something of my own.

Comment: I like your answer starting with "EDIT". I suggest you delete the first part, however. Firstly, if one number is 11, won't it be counted in two intervals? Secondly, the entire array of random numbers must traversed for each range of 10, making this much less efficient than what you do later. (The following is not just "easier".) I find the reference to edits distracting and unnecessary. Why don't you just clean it up without giving us your thinking over time?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: 1) No, because I used `...`. not `..`. 2) the first solution is more general, for any collection of ranges, in case a mathematical shortcut could not be found.

Comment: I missed the three dots, which I seem prone to do, which is why I always use two dots, even if I have to add `-1`. The benefit of generality that you mention does not seem relevant here, but if that's why you gave the initial solution you should say so in the answer. As it now reads I'm sure I'm not the only one who noticed that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: "even easier, by exploiting a simple mathematical property" implies that the top solution does not do so, so existence of such a property is not required. Regarding three dots vs two dots, do you also get confused between `-` and `+` (it's just one extra vertical line, after all)? It's a part of the language, there's no reason not to use it. Also, arguably, `...` is more useful of the two, if you had to pick one to keep.

Comment: Since the array is already sorted, you could also use `chunk` instead of `group_by`.

Comment: And if you already chunk / group by `(x - 1) / 10 * 10 + 1`, you can shorten your output to `[k, k + 9, "#" * v.count]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a *counting hash*.

```
(a = (Array.new(20){|x| x=(rand(1..100)) })).sort!
  #=> [3, 12, 17, 17, 20, 31, 32, 43, 47, 50, 62, 65, 70, 83, 87, 89, 92, 94, 97, 98] 

g = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |n,h|
  interval_first = 1+10*((n-1)/10)
  h[interval_first..interval_first+9] += 1
end
  #=> {1..10=>1, 11..20=>4, 31..40=>2, 41..50=>3, 61..70=>3, 81..90=>3, 91..100=>4}
```

Notice that

```
g[21..30] #=> 0
g[51..60] #=> 0
```

even though `g` does not have keys `21..30` and `51..60`.

If intervals with values of zero are to be included in `g`, this is one way that could be done:

```
g = 10.times.map { |i| [1+10*i..10+10*i, 0] }.to_h
  #=> {1..10=>0, 11..20=>0, 21..30=>0, 31..40=>0, 41..50=>0, 51..60=>0,
  #    61..70=>0, 71..80=>0, 81..90=>0, 91..100=>0}

a.each_with_object(g) do |n,h|
  interval_first = 1+10*((n-1)/10)
  h[interval_first..interval_first+9] += 1
end
  # => {1..10=>1, 11..20=>4, 21..30=>0, 31..40=>2, 41..50=>3, 51..60=>0,
  #     61..70=>3, 71..80=>0, 81..90=>3, 91..100=>4}
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Note that pre-sorting the array of random numbers is of no benefit with this method. That probably holds true with most approaches one might consider.

Comment: The hash does not necessarily contain all ranges.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. You'll see that I did an edit to address that (before I saw your comment, actually). btw, you missed a small error that I made. I'm disappointed.

Comment: My espresso machine is still heating up ☕️

Answer (score 0):

```
(0..100).step(10).each_cons(2).map do |min, max|
  ar.count { |number| number.between?(min.next, max) }
end
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of traversing the list of random numbers once for each interval of 10.

Comment: @CarySwoveland actually, this is still linear (given that the number of ranges is constant). (:

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)